# Unable to copy files within the bucket

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, copy, key, boto

I am trying to copy the files within the bucket from one folder to another

**Code:**

```
src_bucket = s3_conn.get_bucket('ABC')

for k in src_bucket.list(prefix='AB_Test/OUT/gelnique_'):
    print "Processing"

     # Get Destination file name
    src_file = str(k.name)
    index = src_file.find('gelnique_')
    dst_file = src_file[:index] + 'Archive/' + src_file[index:]
    print dst_file

     # copy stuff to your destination here
    src_bucket.copy_key(dst_file, src_bucket, src_file )
```

**Error:**

```
Error><Code>NoSuchBucket</Code><Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message><BucketName>&lt;Bucket:
```

Here dst_file and src_file is a string ,so what the issue here with src_bucket?

Answer (score 0):

oops. 
I Forgot to use the bucket_name as string. That is **src_bucket.name**

```
 src_bucket.copy_key(dst_file, src_bucket.name, src_file )
```